# How to iterate through JSON

Tags: json, swift

I have a method which performs a GET request to an API:

```
public func getApiData(completion: @escaping () -> (), fullUrl: String)
{
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: fullUrl)!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) -> Void in
        if let data = data {

            self.serializeToJSON(jsonData: data)
            completion()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Using SwiftyJSON I then convert the data into JSON:

```
private func serializeToJSON(jsonData: Data) {

    self.json = JSON(data: jsonData)

    print(self.json)

    for (index,item) in self.json {
        print("hi")
    }
}
```

Printing the full JSON gives:

```
[{"TenantID":1,"Tenant1":"RAC"},{"TenantID":2,"Tenant1":"VictorMillwell"},{"TenantID":3,"Tenant1":"Comfort"},{"TenantID":4,"Tenant1":"Greenlight"}]
```

However the JSON can't be iterated through as the `print("hi")` isn't executed, I'm not sure why, I've looked everywhere on the internet to understand why it doesn't iterate and I cant seem to understand why.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Since your JSON is an array and you’re looking for a key,item tuple, maybe you want `for (index, item) in self.json.enumerated()`? Not sure why that’d prevent iteration though...

Comment: @RobHogan Still no luck :(

Comment: Would be pretty easy if you would drop SwiftyJSON and use Codable. Basically, turning this JSON into an array of Tenant structs is a one-liner.

Comment: Also, unclear why you are saying serialize _to_ JSON. You are starting with JSON and trying to decode _from_ JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-parse-json-using-swiftyjson), but in the [manual](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#loop) it says you can loop like this:

```
// If json is .Dictionary
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in self.json {
    // Do something you want
}

// If json is .Array
// The `index` is 0..<json.count's string value
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in self.json {
    // Do something you want
}
```

if you don't know if it's a dictionary or array, maybe you can do it like this:

```
switch self.json.type {
    case .array:
        for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in self.json {
            // Do something you want
        }
    case .dictionary:
        for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in self.json {
            // Do something you want
        }
    default:
        // Do some error handling
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you want to enumerate the JSON. It's trivial to decode this JSON in Swift 4:

```
struct Tenant:Decodable { let TenantID:Int; let Tenant1:String }
let arr = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Tenant].self, from: data)
```

Now `arr` is a Swift array of Tenant, where each Tenant has a `TenantID` property and a `Tenant1` property. And now you can do whatever you like with that array, including cycling through it if you wish.

Comment: Don’t force-unwrap `try`. It will cause a crash if the decoding fails and you won’t even know what the error was. Use `do`/`catch` and `try` without unwrapping.